# Add Custom Portlet in my Header Liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-hook

I want to add a custom porlet in my header of my liferay, but I don't know how to do it.

I know I can add just content in portal....vm. But for a entire portlet..

Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `$theme.runtime('portletIDofCustomPortlet')' in portal_normal.vm in order to add custom portlet in theme.

Comment: How can i get this id ?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible !! You will have to embed the portlet from the thema for the header or leave the space to be able to enter there your portlet

```
#set ($portlet_id = '73')
#set ($instance_id = 'E3j7')
#set ($my_portlet_id = "${portlet_id}_INSTANCE_${instance_id})
```

You need the portlet ID to be able to use it in your header

Documentacion: https://web.liferay.com/es/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Embedding+a+portlet+in+the+theme

Comment: Your answer is missing the main point of the linked article: how to include the portlet. Please add the relevant portions - otherwise it is hard to understand.

Comment: how do you get the portlet id of my personal portlet ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this line in your .vm theme file:

```
$theme.runtime($portletId, $queryString, $velocityPortletPreferences.toString())
```

You can get Portlet ID from "Look and feel" > "Advanced Styling" of your portlet

If it is something like: `#portlet_welcome_WAR_Helloportlet`, you will use
`welcome_WAR_Helloportlet` in place of ID in the theme.

To have more information on how this work and how to use correctly this approach i suggest to follow informations you can find [here](https://community.liferay.com/it/blogs/-/blogs/embedding-portlets-in-themes-on-liferay) and [here](https://community.liferay.com/it/forums/-/message_boards/message/47566400).